# How to bring a legend down without getting overlapped by the bar for a composite chart?

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I created a composite chart with the following legend code.

```
.legend(dc.legend().x(15).y(165).itemHeight(8).gap(3))
```

for that I got my chart as,
[image]

But I need my chart as, 
[image]
Please tell me, how to change the code to avoid legend overlap!